# Android: Finding dynamically made Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm learning Android via http://developer.android.com/training. There's a code to add fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, article_fragment).commit();
```

and it works, but I can't do this

```
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
```

cause there's no article_fragment in R.java yet. Am I'm missing something or is it bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use container id `ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);` or find by tag.

Comment: Now says it can't cast android.support.v4.app.Fragment to com.example.myapplication.ArticleFragment. This means that this is function from support lib? What is equivalent for built-in lib?

Comment: ArticleFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment or android.app.Fragment?

Comment: I assumed android.app.Fragment function is getFragmentManager() and it compiled, but now I'm having "MyApp has stopped working".

Comment: you should use android.support.v4.app.Fragment. This is implementation for older android platforms. When you use getSupportFragmentManager() you should use other support fragment api like android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: you can easy change from android.app to android.support.v4.app

Comment: I changed it to android.support.v4.app and getting "My app has stopped working" :/

Comment: Can you show exception stack trace from logcat, because to say "My app has stopped working" - it is nothing to say.

Comment: com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.myapplication.HeadlinesFragment cannot be cast to com.example.myapplication.ArticleFragment
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onArticleSelected(MainActivity.java:50)
at com.example.myapplication.HeadlinesFragment.onListItemClick(HeadlinesFragment.java:62)
I don't get this. I've downloaded this very example from developer.android.com/shareables/training/FragmentBasics.zip and copied code. They've used "article_fragment" although it has never been declared (so it isn't in R.java).

Comment: I downloaded this example and opened. Everything is ok. I suggest you to remove you project (as i understand you have modified your current and count of problems tends to infinity) download unmodified and open it using "Create android project from existing code"

Comment: I was just going to do that when I read your answer. It works. Seems they mixed example 1's news_article.xml with example 3's. But I left news_article.xml from example 2 so it didn't have article_fragment. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using the tags:

First change the way you add the fragment to your activity, for example:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, yourArticleFragment, "fragment_tag").commit();
```

Then just get back the `Fragment` using the tag "fragment_tag" used as a parameter above:

```
ArticleFragment yourArticleFragment = (ArticleFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("fragment_tag");
```